# How to delete a specific element not using getElementById?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, how can I remove all elements `li class=""`..." between `ul id="videos_list">` except the one who has an "a id="id_defined_here""?
The "ul id="videos_list">" cannot be removed.

```
//Above, other classes and stuff.
 <ul id="videos_list">
    <li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
    <li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);">
        <a id="a_32447256" class="aVideo" ai="2474759"> … </a> 
        <p> … </p>
        <p class="list_lastUp" style="display: block;"> … </p>
        <div class="visuVideo" original-title="visualões"> … </div>
    </li>
    <li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
    <li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
</ul>
//Bellow, other classes and stuff.
```

Here is what i tried to do, but did not work.

```
var myNode = document.getElementById('videos_list'); 
while( myNode.firstChild ) {
    if( !myNode.firstChild.firstChild.getElementById('a_32447256') {//Id of the example.
        myNode.removeChild( myNode.firstChild );
    }
}
```

The only "li class=""...>" who must not be removed is that one who has a child with id=a_32447256. That's why i used
myNode.firstChild.firstChild, but did not work!

What can i do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = document.getElementById('videos_list'),
    target = document.getElementById('a_32447256');

while (list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}
list.appendChild(target.parentNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ul  = document.getElementById('videos_list'),
    li  = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    not = document.getElementById('a_32447256').parentNode;

for (var i=li.length; i--;) {
    if ( li[i] != not ) ul.removeChild(li[i]);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9A9ze/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#videos_list > li')).forEach(function(element){
    if(element.querySelector('a_32447256').length <1){
        document.querySelector('#videos_list').removeChild(element);
    }
})
```

Check to see if #a_32447256 is in the li element.

If no, remove the li element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keep = document.getElementById('a_32447256').parentNode;
var root = document.getElementById('videos_list');

[].slice.call(root.children).forEach(function(node) {
   if ( node !== keep ) this.removeChild(node);
}, root);
```